# Get Error on Flutter - Navigator operation requested

Tags: flutter, dart

i just want to make a simple Task to open the File-Explorer. I tried file_picker but this wasn't working (i tried for about 10h - nearly everything) so i switched to filesystem_picker.
When the Button is pressed, following errors appear:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
#0      Navigator.of.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2553:9)
#1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2560:6)
#2      FilesystemPicker.open (package:filesystem_picker/src/picker_page.dart:58:22)
#3      _App._pickAFile (package:projekt/main.dart:26:41)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
#9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:563:9)
#10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
#12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
#14     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
#15     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:439:19)
#16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
#17     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:322:11)
#18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#19     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#22     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1444:13)
#23     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#24     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#25     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:169:10)
#26     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
#27     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:88:31)
```

The Code is:

```
mport 'dart:io';
import 'package:filesystem_picker/filesystem_picker.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main () => runApp(App());

class App extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _App();
  }
}

class _App extends State<App>{
  Directory rootPath = new Directory('/');

  String? filePath;
  String? dirPath;

  //FileTileSelectMode filePickerSelectMode = FileTileSelectMode.checkButton;

void _pickAFile() async{

  String? path = await FilesystemPicker.open(
  
  title: 'Open file',
  context: context,
  rootDirectory: rootPath,
  fsType: FilesystemType.file,
  folderIconColor: Colors.teal,
  allowedExtensions: ['.pdf'],
  fileTileSelectMode: FileTileSelectMode.wholeTile,
);

}

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(title: Text("FilePickerApp"),
       ),
       body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            newPadding(),

          ],
        ),
       ))
       );
  }

Padding newPadding() {
    // ignore: unnecessary_new
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 20.0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed:_pickAFile,
          // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
          child: Text("Open File picker"),
                ),
              );
  }

}
```

What should i try to fix this? Or is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried with Emulator or Physical device ? Added file read permission  ?

Comment: i've tried with a physical device without permissions, how can i add them?

Comment: {flutter_project_folder}/android/app/src/main in this path open file called AndroidManifest.xml and add this line in 'Mainfest' tag <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: did also not worked.. so the project is new, i try ReactNative instead of Flutter but thanks!

Comment: You have to wrapp all your widgets inside a material app. The Navigator is available via the material app by default.

Answer (score 0):

**try this, maybe it can help**

```
main () => runApp(
MaterialApp(App()),

);
```

and don't return padding here. It maybe like this

```
newPadding() {
   return   Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 20.0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed:_pickAFile,
          
          child: const Text("Open File picker"),
                ),
              );
  }
```